# why can't I set checkbox value from javascript?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter and I'm trying to set the checkbox's checked setting from javascript because I need the javascript function. But why won't it work? The default is still checked and I don't know why

```
document.getElementById("sm").checked = false;
```

The codeigniter code:

```
<?php echo form_checkbox('sm', '1', 'id="sm"'); ?>
```

Comment: can u post a bit more code so that we can get a clear picture.

Comment: Did you look at the HTML? Is the `javascript` executed? In general it is working. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4j7hr/).

Comment: I tried another javascript code "document.form_name.sm.checked = false;" and it works. I don't know what's wrong with the previous one. But, thanks anyway everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Please, try as follow:

```
var chk = document.getElementById("sm");
chk.checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter of form_checkbox is wrong. It should be TRUE or FALSE, not 'id="sm"' (which equals true).

So do this instead:

```
<?php echo form_checkbox('sm', '1', FALSE); ?>
```

If you need additional data, try a data array as follows:

```
$data = array(
    'name'        => 'newsletter',
    'id'          => 'newsletter',
    'value'       => 'accept',
    'checked'     => TRUE,
    'style'       => 'margin:10px',
    );

echo form_checkbox($data);

// Would produce:

<input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="newsletter" value="accept" checked="checked" style="margin:10px" />
```

Example taken from: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: Thank you. It's correct if I'm using the default value from the php controller. But I wanted to pass the default value from javascript instead, and I've found a way to solve my problem on my comment in my question.